# How to print out the parent and child nodes of the tree structure in java？

Tags: java, list, tree

I have some parent and child nodes, and I want to print them out through a tree structure.

It looks like this:

```
Child : Parent
    bb : aa
    cc : aa
    dd : cc
    ee : cc
    ff : ee
```

I hope the final output result is the following tree structure：

```
  aa
    ├── bb
    │   ├── dd
    │   │   └── ff
    │   └── ee   
    └── cc
    |   ├── gg
    |   └── hh
```

In Java, how should we write to convert such a list to a tree? There is now a node that contains the id and name of the parent and child nodes：

```
static class Node{
    int id;
    int parentId;
    String name;
    public Node(int id,int parentId,String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.parentId=parentId;
    }
}
```

A list is defined in the main method to put these parent and child nodes，like this：

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Node>nodeList = Arrays.asList(
            new Node(1,0,"aa"),
            new Node(2,1,"bb"),
            new Node(3,1,"cc"),
            new Node(4,3,"dd"),
            new Node(5,3,"ee"),
            new Node(6,2,"ff"),
            new Node(7,2,"gg"),
            new Node(8,4,"hh"),
            new Node(9,5,"ii"),
            new Node(10,0,"jj"),
            new Node(11,10,"kk"),
            new Node(12,10,"ll"));
    print(nodeList);
}
```

I thought how to solve it the first time，I have tried to write in this way, which is to convert list to map：

```
public static  Map<String, Node> buildIdMap(List<Node>nodeList){
    Map<String, Node> result = new HashMap<>();
    if(targets!=null && !targets.isEmpty()){
        final Iterator<Node> iterator = targets.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            final Node next = iterator.next();
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(next.getId())){
                result.put(next.getId(),next);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then converted to tree output，such as，

```
public List<Node> getTree(List<Node> all ){
    final List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final Map<String, Node> allMap = buildIdMap(all);
    final Iterator<Node> iterator = all.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        final Node next = iterator.next();
        final String parentId = next.getParentId();
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(parentId)){
            final Node node = allMap.get(next.getId());
            final Node nodeP = allMap.get(parentId);
            if(nodeP != null){
                nodeP.getChildren().add(node);
            }
        }else{
            next.setOpen(true);
            result.add(next);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, I can't write it out, it feels like my method is wrong. My purpose is that the final output is a tree structure.

Comment: What do you mean with: *But I can’t write it out, I don’t know if the method is used incorrectly.* Is the output wrong? Or does your method not work?

Comment: Yes, I feel that my thinking is wrong and the output is wrong

Comment: Can't it be written like this? I think others can write like this

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a list of children of each `Node` and then recursively iterate on each `Node` and for each of its child, print `child.name` : `parent.name`.

E.g.

**Node Class:**

```
    static class Node{
        private final String name;
        private final List<Node> children;

        public Node(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public String getName() { return name; }

        public void addChildren(Node... nodes) {
            this.children.addAll(Arrays.asList(nodes));
        }

        public List<Node> getChildren() {
            return this.children;
        }
    }
```

**print(...) method:**

```
    public static void print(Node parent) {
        if (parent == null)
            return;

        for (Node child : parent.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%5s", child.getName()) + " : " + String.format("%6s", parent.getName()));
        }

        for (Node child : parent.getChildren()) {
            print(child);
        }
    }
```

**Example Usage:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Node> m = new HashMap<>();

        for (String name : Arrays.asList("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh")) {
            m.put(name, new Node(name));
        }

        m.get("aa").addChildren(m.get("bb"), m.get("cc"));
        m.get("bb").addChildren(m.get("dd"), m.get("ee"));
        m.get("dd").addChildren(m.get("ff"));
        m.get("cc").addChildren(m.get("gg"), m.get("hh"));

        System.out.println("Child : Parent");
        print(m.get("aa"));
    }
```

**Input:**

```
   aa
    ├── bb
    │   ├── dd
    │   │   └── ff
    │   └── ee   
    └── cc
    |   ├── gg
    |   └── hh
```

**Output:**

```
Child : Parent
   bb :     aa
   cc :     aa
   dd :     bb
   ee :     bb
   ff :     dd
   gg :     cc
   hh :     cc
```

**Edit:**
If you want to print the output visualizing the node's depth in the tree as well, then you can update the print function like this:

```
    public static void printLevel(Node curr, int depth) {
        if (curr == null)
            return;

        for (int i=1; i<=depth-1; i++) {
            System.out.print("│\t");
        }

        if (depth > 0)
            System.out.print("├──");

        System.out.println(curr.name);

        for (Node child : curr.getChildren()) {
            printLevel(child, depth + 1);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
aa
├──bb
│   ├──dd
│   │   ├──ff
│   ├──ee
├──cc
│   ├──gg
│   ├──hh
```

Comment: What if I want its effect to be a tree like this？                                                                           
 aa
    ├── bb
    │   ├── dd
    │   │   └── ff
    │   └── ee   
    └── cc
    |   ├── gg
    |   └── hh

Comment: I mean, what if I want it to output a tree like this, instead of inputting this number and outputting this parent-child node                                                                                                               aa
    ├── bb
    │   ├── dd
    │   │   └── ff
    │   └── ee   
    └── cc
    |   ├── gg
    |   └── hh

Comment: I probably understand what you mean, but this changed my original intention, that is, the ‘print’ is passed into the list<Node>.   Is there a better way? Without changing the ‘Node’ and ‘main’ methods, Get the same result now

Comment: You need to have the children of a particular node at hand to print the tree in this way. If you want to keep the interface of print() intact, then I think you might need to make a map of (parent, children) in the print method and perform DFS on the tree iteratively,